# Subtraction App Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I'm a college student and I'm struggling with an app I have to make. The app is a subtraction app and I can't seem to get it to work. Every time I press the subtraction button it crashes.

My code:

```
public void onClick(View view){

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.subtract_button:

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            EditText firstNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_box_1);
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText().toString());

            EditText secondNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_box_2);
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.getText().toString());

            int result = num1 - num2;

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

            TextView subResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result_view);
            subResult.setText(Integer.toString(result));

            break;

        case R.id.exit_button: // the 'exit' button has been pressed.
            // Delay the exit by 1 second at this time!
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Finish the app
                    finish();
                }
            }, 1000);
            break; // End of case.

    }
}
```

Comment: post logcat please .

Comment: Don't use `setContentView()` anywhere other than your onCreate, and certainly not multiple times with different layouts. Instead use different acitivities each with their own layout

Comment: what is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);`

Comment: Sorry im a bit new to programming, ive not long just started. This is how my Lecturer has taught me. The errors I am reviving are:

Comment: Too long to post here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First Post your **Logcat**

1. Problem for your wrong **`setContentView`** placing .
2. Why multiple `setContentView` ?? Must be **One** .

**Don't**

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.subtract_button:

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Problem here i guess
```

**Do**

1. **setContentView** call in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` section.

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost
>   all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes
>   care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with
>   setContentView(View).

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you missed button declaration check it

```
Button button;
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
```

or else post ur log